# Is there a way to listen to log events via websocket with web3py

Tags: web3js, web3.py, logs, websocket

i am trying to listen to log events via my node's websocket server but i can't seem to find a way to do that using the web3Py lib. the [asynchronous implementation of the docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#running-the-event-loop-in-a-separate-thread) is basically a threaded loop that queries the node every amount of time. this would work if i have a single contract or even to look at but when having multiple filters to look at individually, this can be very resource consuming.

is there a way to implement the websocket log filtering with web3py, considering it is available in the web3js implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web3.py doesn't offer methods to subscribe automatically so we have to manually listen to the websocket and use rpc methods to send the subscription to logs :

```
import asyncio
import json

from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware # only needed for PoA networks like BSC
import requests
from websockets import connect
from eth_abi import decode_single, decode_abi

adapter = requests.sessions.HTTPAdapter(pool_connections=50000, pool_maxsize=50000) # pool connections and max size are for HTTP calls only, since we are using WS they are not needed. 
session = requests.Session()
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("ws://<Provider>"))
w3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0) # only needed for PoA networks like BSC


async def get_event():
    async with connect("ws://localhost:8545") as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps({"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["logs", {
                    "address": ['0x15c921AF5F49a42......'],
                    "topics": [w3.keccak(text="Sync(uint112,uint112)").hex()]}]}))
        subscription_response = await ws.recv()
        print(subscription_response)
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                decoded = decode_single('(uint112,uint112)',bytearray.fromhex(json.loads(message)['params']['result']['data'][2:]))
                print(list(decoded))
                pass
            except:
                pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

after getting the data for the logs we decode them using `eth_abi` and extract the log data. this is a much better option than creating a web3 contract and waiting for the receipt to get the logs that we will have to filter based on topics.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use web3-proxy-providers and subscribe to the event

web3-proxy-providers is a python package for connecting to HTTP and WebSocket Json-RPC using Socks and HTTP proxies

Sample Code:

```py
import asyncio
from Crypto.Hash import keccak
from web3 import Web3
from python_socks import ProxyType
from web3_proxy_providers import AsyncSubscriptionWebsocketWithProxyProvider

async def callback(subs_id: str, json_result):
    print(json_result)

async def main(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop):
    provider = AsyncSubscriptionWebsocketProvider(
        loop=loop,
        endpoint_uri='wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<YourAlchemyKey>',
    )
    
    # subscribe to Deposit and Withdrawal events for WETH contract
    weth_contract_address = Web3.to_checksum_address('0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2')
    deposit_topic = "0x" + keccak.new(data=b'Deposit(address,uint256)', digest_bits=256).hexdigest()
    withdrawal_topic = "0x" + keccak.new(data=b'Withdrawal(address,uint256)', digest_bits=256).hexdigest()
    subscription_id = await provider.subscribe(
        [
            'logs',
            {
                "address": weth_contract_address,
                "topics": [deposit_topic, withdrawal_topic]
            }
        ],
        callback
    )
    print(f'Subscribed with id {subscription_id}')
    print(f'Subscribed with id {subscription_id}')
    
    # unsubscribe after 30 seconds
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    await provider.unsubscribe(subscription_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    async_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async_loop.run_until_complete(main(loop=async_loop))
```

Disclaimer: I am the owner of this package
https://github.com/sinarezaei/web3-proxy-providers