# What are the best options to listen to smart contract events in real time using websockets with web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, events, web3.py

I am currently building a dapp, it has a backend that should listen to the smart contract events to check if a transaction happened or not.

To my knowledge web3.js provides a way to subscribe to events with websocket providers like infura through such method:

```
myContract.events.MyEvent({
    filter: {myIndexedParam: [20,23], myOtherIndexedParam: '0x123456789...'}, // Using an array means OR: e.g. 20 or 23
    fromBlock: 0
}, function(error, event){ console.log(event); })
.on("connected", function(subscriptionId){
    console.log(subscriptionId);
})
.on('data', function(event){
    console.log(event); // same results as the optional callback above
})
.on('changed', function(event){
    // remove event from local database
})
.on('error', function(error, receipt) { // If the transaction was rejected by the network with a receipt, the second parameter will be the receipt.
    ...
});
```

how can i achieve the same thing with web3.py since my backend is built with django?

currently I constantly polling the infura node every second like this:

```
def handle_event(event):
    print(event)
    # and whatever


def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
        time.sleep(poll_interval)


def main():
    block_filter = w3.eth.filter('latest')
    worker = Thread(target=log_loop, args=(block_filter, 5), daemon=True)
    worker.start()
        # .. do some other stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: check this out, it might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98995/is-there-a-way-to-listen-to-log-events-via-websocket-with-web3py

Comment: thank you, i really appreciate your help!